# Google Play Warning

Tags: android, android-security, backendless

So now I've got this message from Google Play saying my app is at a security risk:

> WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError

Now this seems to be a common message as I've seen many post about it.
But in my case, I'm not sure why. I don't use this WebViewClient in my app. Though I do use Backendless as my mBaas provider, and I suspect it's related to that. Not sure though.

Now I'm not sure how I would be able to debug my way to the cause of this. So I'm asking if anyone could have some clue on where to look?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475761/override-onreceivedsslerror-does-not-work-with-android-kitkat-web-view

Comment: `You should remove your onReceivedSslError method.` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218775/google-play-warning-webviewclient-onreceivedsslerror-handler

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya , I don't have such a method. At least not in any file I've been working in. That's why I read those other post about this message and couldn't identify my own problem in any of them.

Comment: Did you get an email listing which class had the vulnerable code?

Comment: @Antimony I've been searching through my entire inbox for that message. But I fear I had that function disabled by default in Google Play. So it's up to if they send another one.

Comment: What is the package name of the app?